# Cannot download sources from remote maven repository, but from local all is fine

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, maven-source-plugin

I have 2 java projects: `payment-common` and `payment-service`.
In `payment-common` I added `maven-siurce-plugin`:

```
<project>
    <builds>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

if I run `mvn clean package`, I see `sources.jar` in target:

[image]

I see also this .jar file in our remote repository after `mvn clean deploy`:

[image]

I have the next dependency in project `payment-service`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.***</groupId>
    <artifactId>payment-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.540.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If I trying to download sources in Idea, I’m getting the next error:

[image]

And then. I run `mvn clean install`, after them I can successfully download sources.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**: repositories in pom.xml:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudfront-snapshots</id>
            <name>***</name>
            <url>https://maven.***.net/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Are you pointing that artifactory (i guess aws s3) as a repository URL on your pom file?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni, Yes. In 3 pathes 1: `repositories.repository` 2: `distributionManagement.repository` 3: `distributionManagement.snapshotRepository`.

Comment: Have you done ```mvn clean install -U``` Make sure when you do that, ```mvn``` prints the searching for your jar file in the repository URL you have mentioned

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni, Yup: Downloading: s3://***-maven-repo/com/***/common-constants/1.540.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: This shows your jar is uploaded successfully. Are you getting this error when you download sources through your IDEA

Comment: Yes, when downloading in IDEA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204767/discussion-between-siddarth-sreeni-and-pegoopik).